# Flutter: Unable to convert string into a widget that acts as a navigator path

Tags: flutter, navigation, material-design

item.info is string 'Page2()'. I surrounded it with a widget text because you have to return a widget to this function. Instead of being taken to Page2 screen. It prints Page2() instead.

How do I convince flutter that this is a path to another page?

```
  onPressed: () {
                print('My infopage : ${Text(item.info)}');
                Navigator.push(
                   context,
                   MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Text(item.info)));

                          //builder: (context) => const Page2()));
                },
```

Comment: Why not give the actual widget you want to navigate to? Why do you want to navigate by a string?

Comment: it should be Navigator.pushNamed if you're going by named route